# Razor page views with Partial (nested) views

Tags: c#, razor-pages, partial-views, .net-6.0

I broke down bigger "Razor page" views into to "Partial" views.

From the main views I pass e.g. an image list to the partial view:

```
<partial name="/Partial/_ImageList.cshtml" model="ImageList" />
```

These partial views now starts to grow, and gets less simple/clean/readable.

So to solve that, I looked into doing something like this, in either the main or partial view:

```
foreach (var item in Model.ImageList)
{
    <partial name="/Partial/@item.some_property_view" model="item" />
}
```

With this I can have several smaller partial views, some also reusable cross different types of lists, instead of many `if-then-else` statement in a bigger view one.

To keep things simple/clean/readable, it appears (to me) this is the way to do it.

Given I have no long term experience with these things, and based on my own knowledge, where one learn about do's/dont's not found in any documentation;

- Is there is anything else to consider, pros/cons when breaking down a bigger view to many smaller, that any of you ran into overtime?

My main concern is of course performance, though for a small number of items, 10-20, it likely wont matter, but will it if there are +200 items?...or at +1000?

*I am aware of `View Components`, though I assume compiling many smaller of those, compared to `Partial views`, would have similar benefits/issues, but if not, please let me know.*

**Update**

An `ImageList` item has about 5-8 properties, 1-2 is a header (50-100 characters each), 1-2 is a text (250-500 characters each), 1-2 is an image link and 1-2 is a hyperlink/anchor link.

Comment: If partial views are getting out of hand, looking into writing custom tag helpers. Tag helpers allow you to have any complexity of code and are very clean in your markup.

Comment: @JonathanWood -- Thanks, I did, but I really need the templating functions, where I pass a model to be mapped to a HTML structure, where I can make use of "if-then-else" to select which element to be used, and with what value.

Comment: @JonathanWood -- Also, today I do some "home-made-mapping" using a HTML snippet and  `string.Format`, though much more work to adjust when the model changes, and, given my system is a CMS solution, I can't reuse cross clients unless they both want the same properties. And start doing "if-then-else" in a tag helper seems to defeat its purpose...right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted - rendering a large amount of items is not recommended on both client and server side.

Why?

- Server Side - require high computing + networking resources for a single connection and may overload the entire solution
- Client side - overload the DOM with too much of HTML elements - most of them are not even viewable by the user in a given moment

Because this is a known issue, there is a solution to solve it - virtual scroll (aka infinite scroll) - which is the "modern" way to do pagination. In this excellent [article](https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1) there is a comparison between "classic" pagination and "modern" virtual scroll (at least in terms of user experience)

**To the point:** Microsoft provides a built-in virtualization mechanism to assist you solve this problem with ease (no need to implement your own pagination mechanism). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) also provide a simple example to assist you keep going (before and after virtualization)

Based on the code you share I assume that you will change your loop from this

```
foreach (var item in Model.ImageList)
{
    <partial name="/Partial/@item.some_property_view" model="item" />
}
```

to this

```
<Virtualize Items="Model.ImageList" Context="item">
    <partial name="/Partial/@item.some_property_view" model="item" />
</Virtualize>
```

Because I really don't know how much data you load into you `ImageList` and if you need to reduce the number of items there - please refer to [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#item-provider-delegate) of the documentation in order to have a better control over your pagination mechanism (by loading current "page" of items instead of virtualizing the entire data set)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, you made a good point here, bringing up `Virtualize` as an aspect. FYI, the "how much data into `ImageList`" is generally 10-20 items, that holds 5-6 properties each (will update my answer with that, as it might affect how to go about this), which likely is not make any noticeable performance hit, though, as I wrote, at what amount might it ? (+200, +1000, +...).

Comment: Thanks. to your question: as a rule of thumb - when you are getting more than 150 items you are entering a realm of high-loads. keep in mind to properly split your data into pages in order to better control loads and provide a better user experience (user will prefer to get partial but faster results then having to wait for a long period of time)